# fill page(s) with (long) table //move long tablularx to the left of the page [scrlttr2]

Tags: koma-script, tabularx, ltablex

I tried to move the table to the left of the page, but was not successful.
The table did not move at all. If I prepend a normal text with `\hspace`, it works as expected.
How can I move the table to the left?

The actual goal is to fill the page horizontally with the table (its a table over multiple pages)

```latex
\documentclass[]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{tabularx,ltablex}
\keepXColumns
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{test}
\opening{open}
\hspace*{-7em}
\begin{tabularx}{1.5\textwidth}{|X|}
TEst
\end{tabularx}
\closing{}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

the use of `adjustwidth` does not help either

```latex
\documentclass[]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{tabularx,ltablex}
\usepackage{changepage} % adjustwidth
\keepXColumns
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{test}
\opening{Test}
{
\begin{adjustwidth}{-10cm}{-10cm}
\begin{tabularx}{1.5\textwidth}{|X|}
TEst
\end{tabularx}
\end{adjustwidth}
}
\closing{}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is neither a KOMA-Script nor a `scrlttr2` issue. You will get the same problem, if you use a standard class, e.g. `article`.

Comment: right, i removed the tag